# Free fall with sound

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, acoustics, free-fall

One of my colleagues affirm that the following problem is not solvable while I think it is.

> Consider a body falling from rest inside a pit/well of unknown's depth ($h$). Taking into account that the speed of sound is finite ($0<v_s<\infty$) and given the total time ($t_{TOT}$) taken to hear the sound, find the depth.

Clearly $t_{TOT}=t_{fall}+t_{climb}=\sqrt{\frac{2h}{g}}+\frac{h}{v_s}$ and so what is left is the following equation
$$gh^2-2v_s(v_s+t_{TOT}g)h+gv_s^2t_{TOT}^2=0$$
And the positive solution will be the answer.

Is that correct?

Comment: What is "the sound"?

Comment: @BioPhysicist The thud when it hits the bottom of the well?

Comment: @Gert Probably. I isn't explicitly stated though

Answer (score 1):

You've done this in your calculation $(a+b)^2 = a^2 +b^2$, but you need to do $(a+b)(a+b)$

including the cross terms

$$gh^2-(2v_s^2+2gv_st)h+v_s^2t_{TOT}^2g=0$$

then you could carry on from there, so in principle it can be solved.

However a model just with free fall would be accurate enough, without including the speed of sound.  If you are going to the trouble of including that, then air resistance should also be included...

Comment: Thx for pointing out my mistake. I've posted without reading. That term was there in the blackboard during my show off with him and that was the only important thing.

Comment: @ yngabi ok, all the best with it, it can be solved with your method now